# Separating gaussian components of a curve using python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian

I am trying to deblend the emission lines of low resolution spectrum in order to get the gaussian components. This plot represents the kind of data I am using:

[image: Input data and gaussian components using the solution of Mduran]

After searching a bit, the only option I found was the application of the gauest function from the kmpfit package (http://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn/kmpfittutorial.html#gauest). I have copied their example but I cannot make it work.

I wonder if anyone could please offer me any alternative to do this or how to correct my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize

def CurveData():
    x = np.array([3963.67285156,  3964.49560547,  3965.31835938,  3966.14111328,  3966.96362305,
         3967.78637695,  3968.60913086,  3969.43188477,  3970.25463867,  3971.07714844,
         3971.89990234,  3972.72265625,  3973.54541016,  3974.36791992,  3975.19067383])
    y = np.array([1.75001533e-16,   2.15520995e-16,   2.85030769e-16,   4.10072843e-16, 7.17558032e-16,
         1.27759917e-15,   1.57074192e-15,   1.40802933e-15, 1.45038722e-15,  1.55195653e-15,
         1.09280316e-15,   4.96611341e-16, 2.68777266e-16,  1.87075114e-16,   1.64335999e-16])
    return x, y

def FindMaxima(xval, yval):
    xval = np.asarray(xval)
    yval = np.asarray(yval)

    sort_idx = np.argsort(xval)
    yval = yval[sort_idx]
    gradient = np.diff(yval)
    maxima = np.diff((gradient > 0).view(np.int8))
    ListIndeces = np.concatenate((([0],) if gradient[0] < 0 else ()) + (np.where(maxima == -1)[0] + 1,) + (([len(yval)-1],) if gradient[-1] > 0 else ()))
    X_Maxima, Y_Maxima = [], []

    for index in ListIndeces:
        X_Maxima.append(xval[index])
        Y_Maxima.append(yval[index])

    return X_Maxima, Y_Maxima

def GaussianMixture_Model(p, x, ZeroLevel):
    y = 0.0
    N_Comps = int(len(p) / 3)
    for i in range(N_Comps):
        A, mu, sigma = p[i*3:(i+1)*3]
        y += A * np.exp(-(x-mu)*(x-mu)/(2.0*sigma*sigma))
    Output =  y + ZeroLevel
    return Output

def Residuals_GaussianMixture(p, x, y, ZeroLevel):    
    return GaussianMixture_Model(p, x, ZeroLevel) - y

Wave, Flux  = CurveData()

Wave_Maxima, Flux_Maxima = FindMaxima(Wave, Flux)

EmLines_Number = len(Wave_Maxima)

ContinuumLevel = 1.64191e-16

# Define initial values
p_0 = []
for i in range(EmLines_Number):
    p_0.append(Flux_Maxima[i])
    p_0.append(Wave_Maxima[i])
    p_0.append(2.0)

p1, conv = optimize.leastsq(Residuals_GaussianMixture, p_0[:],args=(Wave, Flux, ContinuumLevel))

Fig    = plt.figure(figsize = (16, 10))  
Axis1  = Fig.add_subplot(111) 

Axis1.plot(Wave, Flux, label='Emission line')
Axis1.plot(Wave, GaussianMixture_Model(p1, Wave, ContinuumLevel), 'r', label='Fit with optimize.leastsq')
print p1
Axis1.plot(Wave, GaussianMixture_Model([p1[0],p1[1],p1[2]], Wave, ContinuumLevel), 'g:', label='Gaussian components')
Axis1.plot(Wave, GaussianMixture_Model([p1[3],p1[4],p1[5]], Wave, ContinuumLevel), 'g:')

Axis1.set_xlabel( r'Wavelength $(\AA)$',)
Axis1.set_ylabel('Flux' + r'$(erg\,cm^{-2} s^{-1} \AA^{-1})$')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical simplistic way to fit:

```
def model(p,x):
    A,x1,sig1,B,x2,sig2 = p
    return A*np.exp(-(x-x1)**2/sig1**2) + B*np.exp(-(x-x2)**2/sig2**2)

def res(p,x,y):
    return model(p,x) - y

from scipy import optimize

p0 = [1e-15,3968,2,1e-15,3972,2]
p1,conv = optimize.leastsq(res,p0[:],args=(x,y))

plot(x,y,'+') # data
#fitted function
plot(arange(3962,3976,0.1),model(p1,arange(3962,3976,0.1)),'-')
```

Where p0 is your initial guess. By the looks of things, you might want to use Lorentzian functions...

If you use full_output=True, you get all kind of info about the fitting. Also check out curve_fit and the fmin* functions in scipy.optimize. There are plenty of wrappers around these around, but often, like here, it's easier to use them directly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have added your solution (with a few modifications) to the code on the question. I have also added a method to calculate the maxima location. This information is used to give an estimation of the amplitude and the mu. Would you have any suggestion on how to give an initial estimation of the sigmas?

Comment: Hi! You do not need to have a good estimation of the sigmas. In such cases, it is a good idea to keep the positions of the gauss functions fixed, fit all other parameters, and then fit everything again, including the positions.

Comment: Of course I did it by eye, but in general it depends on your data and the specific minimization algorithm you choose. For your data, the 1st moment about the peak gives a good estimate of the typical line-width.

Comment: Sorry Sweber, how would you do that?