# Blurred Y axis title in display window when using latex format (mac os issue?)

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I am experiencing some issues while displaying my plots: The Y title appears to be compressed and/or blurred:
[image]

This distortion only happens when I use the latex text format (this plot code can be found in this question: [Separating gaussian components of a curve using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453451/separating-gaussian-components-of-a-curve-using-python)) and only when I display the image, not when I save it (either directly or using the interface saving shortcut). Somehow, I believe this is due to some installation issue with the code libraries in mac (since in linux I did not have these issues)

Any advice on how to solve this would be most welcome.